# How to output cyrillic in AWS CLI list-objects-v2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, utf-8, command-line-interface

my bucket consist of objects which are named in cyrilic. Unfortunately the output in AWS CLI list-objects-v2 command is totally nonsense like the ones below. How I'm supposed to take the names?

```
34m┴Ёхщ ╩юъю°ш  щЎр ЁрчьхЁ L 6 сЁ ётюсюфэш .jpg
34m├Ёючфх схч ёхьъш .jpg
34m╩╘╠ ╪єэър юЄ яєх°ъю Їшых, ёырщё .jpg
34m╩рЁЄюЇш ьшЄш .jpg
```

Comment: What platform and what version of the platform and aws cli are you using?

Comment: Hi @AnonCoward the 2nd version

Comment: The second version of what?

Comment: @AnonCoward sorry, Windows 10 and CLI version 2